# Scheduled notification suppression for Android

Tags: android, notification

I am not looking to turn-off notifications completely, but instead, I ideally would like to be able to have Android delay all notifications until a certain time in the day, say 21:00, or whenever I decide is a good time to be bothered by Facebook and e-mail distractions. Is there an app for this? If not, what sort of techniques do you use to limit notification distractions barring just turning them off completely?

(Disclaimer:  This was originally asked on [productivity.stackexchange](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/scheduled-notification-suppression-for-android/14098#14098).)

Comment: I have not used any of those apps myself (felt no need yet) – but my site includes a list of apps for [Notification Settings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543) you might wish to check while waiting for "real answers". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**[Daywise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synapse.alarm.daywise)** could be your candidate. You can define which notifications you want to see immediately, and have all others collected to be shown later "in a batch" – when *you* want to see them, not when the apps pop them up. That can either be a scheduled time, or an "inbox" you look at at your convenience.